# How to list out data between 2 tables with different dates each time?

Tags: sql, oracle

How many and What are the tickets that were cancelled 2 weeks or less before the departure date? 
Here is my ERD: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yP13HnbXM5S8P6XsuHYC6svjh1OOKSfr/view?usp=sharing

```
SELECT CANCELID, t.TICKET_ID, DEPART_DATE, CANCELDATE, COUNT(TICKET_ID)
FROM TICKET t, CANCELLATION c
WHERE c.TICKET_ID = t.TICKET_ID AND CANCELDATE = ??
```

It will show the ticket ID and cancel ID along with the total count, and the date difference for each departure date and cancel date

Comment: Replace `AND CANCELDATE = ??` with --> `AND CANCELDATE + interval '14' day >= DEPART_DATE` .. Use `TRUNC`, if time is not needed in comparision.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `JOIN` for this type of query.  To get the list of such tickets:

```
SELECT c.CANCELID, t.TICKET_ID, t.DEPART_DATE, c.CANCELDATE
FROM TICKET t JOIN
     CANCELLATION c
     ON c.TICKET_ID = t.TICKET_ID AND
        c.CANCELDATE >= t.DEPART_DATE - INTERVAL '2' WEEK;
```

If you want the count, then use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of listing out the columns.

Comment: Hey, thank you this works too although i have not learn JOIN yet, i am a student currently studying diploma.

Comment: @ClementLee . . . `JOIN` should be what you learn.  You should not be learning `,`.  It is obsolete and out-dated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query -

```
SELECT CANCELID, t.TICKET_ID, DEPART_DATE, CANCELDATE, COUNT(TICKET_ID)
FROM TICKET t, CANCELLATION c
WHERE c.TICKET_ID = t.TICKET_ID AND CANCELDATE >= (DEPART_DATE - 14)
GROUP BY CANCELID, t.TICKET_ID, DEPART_DATE, CANCELDATE;
```

Comment: Thanks, it really did help me.